# Input com a data do respectivo dia, sem poder ser editado

Tags: html, angularjs

Preciso que um input venha com a data do respectivo dia, por exemplo hoje: 17/11/2015, amanhã 18/11/2015. Esse input não pode permitir edições.

Meu código está assim:

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <span class="cinza input-label">Data:</span>
    <input class="cinza" type="date">
</label>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode atribuir uma variável com a data atual no value do input, e marcar ele como readonly para não ser editado.

```
<input class="cinza" readonly type="date" value="{{data| date:'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}">
```

No controlador,  `$scope.data = new Date();`

Comment: Só tome cuidado, pois o `input="date"` não funciona em todos os navegadores e isso pode te dar bastante dor de cabeça (como está sendo comigo). Então verifique essa necessidade de portabilidade da data.